# How to create to select from year to year in html forms?

Tags: javascript, html, django, forms, select

I want to user to input from this year to that and then I need to forward the list of years to django? But before this how to create that kind of input, I have found something like this, but it is not working what I need. Any ideas?

```
<select name="yearpicker" id="yearpicker"></select>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
let startYear = 1800;
let endYear = new Date().getFullYear();
for (i = endYear; i > startYear; i--)
{
    $('#yearpicker').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
}
</script>
```

Comment: To user select, for example, from 1990 to 2018, and I be able to take that as list, like this years = [1990, 1991, 1992, ..... , 2017, 2018]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen for the `change` event and use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to populate an array from a certain range:

```html
Start: <select name="yearpicker" id="yearpicker"></select>
<br/>
End: <select name="yearpicker2" id="yearpicker2"></select>

<script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
let startYear = 1800;
let endYear = new Date().getFullYear();
for (i = endYear; i > startYear; i--)
{
    $('#yearpicker, #yearpicker2').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
}

$('select').on('change', function(){
  let arr = Array.from({length:$('#yearpicker2').val() - +$('#yearpicker').val()},(v,k)=>k + +$('#yearpicker').val())
  console.log(arr);
})
</script>
```

Comment: This is not bad, but how to user pick an end year (not to always to be 2020)

Comment: @project.py Are you fine with 2 `select` elements?

Comment: Yes, no problem